# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$

Tags: integration, derivatives, functional-equations

For some $n \in N$ and $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ the unique differentiable function such that

$$[f(x)]^{2n+1}+f(x)-x=0$$

for all $x$.

For $x \ge 0$ evaluate

$$\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$$

P.S: I have tried some ideas like derivation of the functional equation and I got that $f(x)>0$ and $f'(x)>0$. Any idea?

Comment: If $n=0$, $f(x)=x/2$. Now let $a:=f(0)$; then the functional equation implies that $a\left(a^{2n}+1\right)=a^{2n+1}+a=0$, so that $f(0)=a=0$. Now differentiating the functional equation yields $f'(0)=-1$ for $n>0$. So, how did you deduce your inequalities?

Comment: $n$ is a constant.

Comment: I agree. This does not affect my computations, and I still do not see how you got your inequalities.

Comment: Derivate the equation and get $f'(x)=1/[(2n+1)(f(x)^{2n})+1]$.

Comment: Okay, there is a typo in what I've written: it is $f'(0)=1$ of course! So now I do not have a contradiction with what you write anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x) = x^{2n+1} + x$. Notice that $g$ is the inverse of $f$. Then with the substitution $u = f(t)$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt
&= \int_{0}^{f(x)} u g'(u) \, du \\
&= x f(x) - \int_{0}^{f(x)} g(u) \, du \tag{*} \\
&= x f(x) - \frac{f(x)^{2n+2}}{2n+2} - \frac{f(x)^2}{2}.
\end{align*}

Notice that $\text{(*)}$ can be rewritten as a more geometrically suggesting form

$$ \int_{0}^{a} f(x) \, dx + \int_{0}^{f(a)} f^{-1}(y) \, dy = af(a). $$

This can be derived by interpreting the left-hand side as the area of the rectangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(a,0)$, $(a,f(a))$, $(0,f(a))$ which is cut through by the graph of $y = f(x)$.